# Char combination with repetition in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops, combinations

sorry for the maybe trivial question, but taken an array of chars ['a', 'b', 'c'] I would like to get as an output a series of char arrays (also List are fine) listing all the 27 combinations, including of course the repetitions. For instance:

```
['a', 'a', 'c']
['a', 'a', 'a']
['c', 'a', 'b']
```

and so on

could you please help me in the implementation?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use 3 nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

Create 3 nested loops that loop trough each element in the array.
Then create a new array inside the nested loops.
Access the values from your array using the variable that you named in the loop as the index.
Should look something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
// 2 more nested loops
// char[] combination = new char[]{array[i], array[j], array[k]};
}
```

I'm assuming that this is some kind of university assignment.
Quick tip would be to always try to find the solution in pseudocode before writing the actual code.
Understand the problem first, find a solution on paper even, and after that you can research on how to apply the solution using specific language syntax.
This snippet should be more than enough to get you going.